# Order By with Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Is there an efficient way to do an order by and group by so that you get a specific item from each group (from the order by).

```
//This is the best way i have come up with.
SELECT D.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM devices
    ORDER BY time
) AS D
GROUP BY D.location
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than `select * from devices group by location`?

Comment: Here is the problem.  Say you have a table that houses a bunch of reports.  Each location can have X reports.  But you only want the latest report.  To achieve this 100% of the time, you must order by time THEN group by.

Comment: I suspect that you may be misunderstanding the operation of GROUP BY. See this article (apologies if this is old news to you) http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM col
      ORDER BY col DESC,date DESC)a
GROUP BY col
```

Comment: Unfortunately its been so long since i looked at this that i do not remember!  :)  But thanks for the answer!

Comment: LOL :) ... I Know, but someone else might stumble upon the same problem and it doesn't hurt to post a second solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM devices
GROUP BY D.location
ORDER BY time --ASC or DESC default is ASC i believe
```

No need for sub-queries

Comment: That errors out.  YOu cannot do an order by statement before a group by statement like that. and yes, ASC is default becuase it is the "Natural Ordering", as in if i asked you to see if i had 100 items, you would probably start at 1 and go to 100 rather than starting at 100 and counting down.

Comment: Does this perform the ORDER BY first or GROUP BY?

Comment: does this perform order by before group by?

Comment: omg... mysql does not allow you to enter in the ORDER BY before the gb. idk, did you try it??

Comment: well.  I wish you did not have to have attitude to a very valid question.  Yes i did, but it was a small sample data so i was not sure and i could not find anything with some google searching on which is performed first.